# How to change python's site-packages path?

Tags: python

Recently I try to install some packages,my python is installed in D:\python,but when I had installed the packages I need,it says "can't find this module"but I truly install this packages in my D:\python
when I try  `python -m site --user-site` in my pycharm terminal,it turns out my computer's site-packages path:
[image]

And when I try `python -m site -help`,it turns out:
[image]
How to change this path to "D:\python\python36\Lib\site-packages"?
Thanks!

Comment: You should uninstall Python3.9 from the Windows Store if you want to use `D:\python\python36`

Comment: "my python is installed in D:\python" - The path in screenshot suggests you installed your python from Windows Store and that's where "python" in console points to. That's your collision.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `py -3.9` instead of `python`. Is `D:\python\python36` in your path ?